# quicksort implementation: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, algorithm

So I'm trying to implement quicksort in ruby  and I get this error `quicksort': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

```
def quicksort(array)
  if array.length <= 1
    return array
  end
  less = Array.new
  greater = Array.new
  pivot = array[array.length/2]
  array.each do |x|
    if x < pivot
      less << x
    else 
      greater << x
    end
  end
  return quicksort(less) << pivot << quicksort(greater)
end
```

EDIT
I changed the `else` to `elsif x > pivot` and it seems to work .

Comment: Quick sort can use up to n levels of stack (in pathological cases), where n is the number of input elements. If this case is reached then only increasing the stack size, choosing a better pivot method (which will only decrease the pathologically bad cases), or changing the quicksort implementation will fix it. If it happens for a small n then the terminal condition is wrong, of course :) What is the [smallest] input that causes this exception?

Comment: Under what conditions are you getting this error?

Comment: I changed the else => elsif x > pivot and it seems to work .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is working for me, even out to 1e7 when I generate an array for testing.

```
 quicksort Range.new(1,1e7).to_a.shuffle
```

Granted, that required about 4.5 GB of RAM to finish.  As far as cleaning up the output...

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :018 >       quicksort [1,3,2] # => [1, 2, [], 3, []] 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :019 >     quicksort [1,4,2,3] # => [1, 2, [3, [4]]]
```

Change this line:

```
  return (quicksort(less) << pivot << quicksort(greater)).flatten.compact
```

And it makes it all much cleaner.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :037 >       quicksort [1,3,2] # => [1, 2, 3] 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :038 >     quicksort [1,4,2,3] # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

you needed to delete pivot out of the array because you're adding it back in later
so instead of

```
pivot = array[array.length/2]
```

you should have done

```
pivot = array.delete_at(array.length/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby the stack size is set fairly small by default. So it's not too hard to blow the stack doing recursive functions with large datasets.

The easiest way to make sure you're not recursing infinitely is to run `quicksort` on a very small dataset. If it still blows up you know you're recursing infinitely.

You can find some info about the stack size in [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/d4d50fb6127933ec?pli=1) that Matz replies to.

Comment: But the stack size should remain very small in Quicksort, unless the implementation breaks down on already-sorted data.  The stack size will be around lg(n) - way less than any scripting language's limit even if the array fills up all of memory!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is recursing infinitely.  Use ruby-debug to find out why.

**EDIT1:**

I think you want the last line of the function to be this:

```
return quicksort(less) + quicksort(greater)
```